# Can you keep a Redux store indefinitely and just keep adding/updating to it?

Tags: reactjs, database, redux, react-redux, store

I'm wondering: if I wanted to, I could probably indefinitely populate a redux store from a REST API and just keep updating whenever I fetch something new until (in theory) I have a local copy of the remote database. If it's flat and has well-designed and implemented relations, I don't suppose I would run into any issues.

Is there any reason why you should regularly reset the state other than performance?

Comment: You could absolutely do this, as long as you don't run out of memory. But yeah, assuming you are rendering React elements based off of database rows or w/e, you will quickly run into performance issues

Comment: It's Javascript everything is possible :)